# Customize kendo ui column bars

Tags: kendo-ui

I have the following kendo ui column chart.

http://dojo.telerik.com/ibijO

I need to make all the bars wider and centered them.
Is that possible through kendo ui configuration, not through css I have changed them through css but now I have problem because the exportImage method export the initial display.

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful (I pulled this from the Telerik forums):

> I am afraid currently there is no built-in option for setting
>   explicitly the bars' widths in Kendo UI Chart. By design the width of
>   the bars depends on gap and spacing. Hence in order manage the bars'
>   widths you can configure the aforementioned properties of the chart.

[Here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/gap-spacing) is a link to a demo of the gap and spacing options. And [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/ISeca) is an updated Dojo.

```
seriesDefaults: {
     type: "column",
     spacing: 0,
     gap: 10
 }
```